# Arakelian's approximation theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I have a difficulty in understanding how one gets relation (2) in the proof of the Theorem, in the nice paper

[Jean-Pierre Rosay and Walter Rudin, Arakelian's Approximation Theorem, The American Mathematical Monthly, vol. 96, No. 5, 1989, pp. 432-434].

More exactly, it seems that relation (1) there must imply this relation (2).

I have tried to prove that, by using the Cauchy-Pompeiu formula for the function (with the notations in that proof)

$$[h_{i-1}(w)-P(w)]. \psi(w)$$

and I get a kind of formula (2), but with the modulus outside of the integral. !

My problem is that I don't understand why in (2), the modulus can be moved inside of the integral sign. ! I tried it for several days but maybe something escapes me. !

I would greatly appreciate if someone would have the patience to look into that point of the proof in the above mentioned paper and give me some hints.

Thank you so much in advance.

Best wishes,
George

Comment: I just took a quick look at the paper and it seems that the proof only uses the fact that the modulus of the integral is small, not that the integral of the modulus is small. Perhaps it is a typo.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the proof works if in (2) the modulus is taken outside of the integral.to be a typo, many, many thanks.